# Make a MySQL backup daily, outside of Google cloud

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

We just try google cloud SQL 2nd generation with fail over, it is quite easy and amazing, it seems we don't have to worry our DB anymore.
But, for more secure our data, we decide we better have some backups that is not host inside google, although it is not necessary, but we have account in IBM cloud, and they got IBM cloud object storage like Amazon S3, which we think might be a good place for backup.
Now we plan doing this on a VPS in IBM datacenter, a Linux server, to connect to Google cloud SQL with root and execute mysqldump to dump all data to 1 or multiples files (in tar,gz maybe), then we use our S3 backup scripts to upload to IBM storage.

We will post our solution & steps when we got answer from you or maybe when we figure out.

Comment: After some search on google, I think below 2 URL are close to my idea.  https://github.com/lumerit/s3-shell-backups  & https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/connecting-cos-s3-using-s3cmd

Answer (score 1):

OK, I am happy I can do some contribute here, if someone want to do things exactly like I am trying to do, pls follow these links before you just copy, also, if you got better way to do it, welcome to help to fix it.
Links to check:
https://github.com/lumerit/s3-shell-backups
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/connecting-cos-s3-using-s3cmd
My scripts based on :
https://gist.github.com/JProffitt71/9044744
https://andycroll.com/development/backing-up-mysql-databases-remotely-using-cron-and-ssh/

1st script , you can named it "deleteold" and remember to chmod 755

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./deleteold "dir-of-your-bucketname" "-30 day"
# Usage-sample-2: ./deleteold "dir-of-your-bucketname" "-500 minutes"

# Pls put your bucketname in s3://here

s3cmd ls s3://my-database-backups/$1/ | while read -r line;
  do
createDate=`echo $line|awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
createDate=`date -d"$createDate" +%s`
### 28800 sec is the time difference between our server & IBM COS
createData=`expr $createData + 28800`
olderThan=`date -d"$2" +%s`
if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]
  then
    fileName=`echo $line|awk {'print $4'}`
    echo $fileName
    if [[ $fileName != "" ]]
      then
        echo $fileName
        s3cmd del "$fileName"
      fi
  fi
 done;
```

2nd script

```
#!/bin/sh

#### BEGIN CONFIGURATION ####

##Account name SLOSC3xx982-4

# set dump directory variables
SRCDIR='/tmp/s3backups'
DESTDIR='google'
BUCKET='my-database-backups'

# database access details
HOST=‘x0x.x9.x4.98'
PORT='3306'
USER='root'
PASS='5xxxyyzznIoi8XXP'
NOW=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M_`

#### END CONFIGURATION ####

# make the temp directory if it doesn't exist and cd into it
mkdir -p $SRCDIR
cd $SRCDIR

# dump each database to its own sql file and upload it to s3
for DB in $(mysql -h$HOST -P$PORT -u$USER -p$PASS -BNe 'show databases' | grep -Ev 
'mysql|information_schema|performance_schema')
do
mysqldump -h$HOST -P$PORT -u$USER -p$PASS --quote-names --create-options --force --set- 
gtid-purged=OFF $DB > $DB.sql
tar -czf $NOW$DB.tar.gz $DB.sql
/usr/bin/s3cmd put $SRCDIR/$NOW$DB.tar.gz s3://$BUCKET/$DESTDIR/ --reduced-redundancy
files="$files $DB"
done

# remove all files in our source directory
cd
rm -f $SRCDIR/*.sql
rm -f $SRCDIR/*.tar.gz
## remove older files
/root/backups3/deleteold "google" "-3 day"
#/root/backups3/deleteold "google" "-490 minutes"

### Mail me ###
EMAILID=“your-name@gmail.com"

mail -s "Backups Report $NOW" $EMAILID << END
Success backup cloud SQL from $HOST to IBM COS $BUCKET
The following databases were attempted backed up
$files
END
```

After put these 2 scripts in /root/backups3 ( you can put it anywhere youu like), setup crontab, to execute 2nd script every day, so that it will use mysqldump to dump all ur databases to a tar.gz file then upload to S3 ( IBM COS or Aws S3, whatever you like).
And you will get an email once it done, and it also will call script 1 to delete old files based on the days or minutes past you want to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could [export your SQL data to a dump file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#mysqldump) which storage the mysqldump in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, then you could transfer this data to an Amazon S3 bucket with the [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#top_of_page)

Comment: we expect to do this in a automatically way.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google doesn't have a service to do this automatically, however, you could do a cron job to do the mysqldump file with the [gcloud 2nd gen](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#mysqldump) commands, then do the transfer by using the [Data Transfer client](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-client#create_a_client)